# xcode how can i remove the top bar from a subview

Tags: ios, swift, subview

[image: how can i remove the bar under the carrier]

i have a sub view in the main view but for some reason the sub view keep show that bar under the carrier text when Im in the in the subview  screen i do not see this bar only when Im in the the main view or previewing the app on the simulator

Answer (score -1):

if you want hide statusBar

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
```

if you want hide navigationBar

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

Comment: The question is tagged "swift". Not "objective-c". Please always provide an answer in the language requested by OP.

Comment: sorry, i am a new hand of stack overflow. I'll pay attention to